# How to determine which bit is set

Tags: c#, bit

I have two bytes, they only differ in 1 bit. I want to know what bit this is.

So:

```
byte a,b;
a=0;
b=2;

ChangedBit(a,b) should give bit 1
ChangedBit(4,5) should give bit 0
ChangedBit(7,3) should give bit 2
```

Any suggestions are very welcome!!

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution would be to do

```
var bit = Math.Log(a ^ b, 2);
```

Although of course this leaves open the question of what happens if for any reason *more* than one bit is different.

You could use

```
var bit = (int)Math.Log(a ^ b, 2);
```

to get you the index of the *highest* different bit, if more than one differ.

**Warning:** For correctness, any such function should also check that the two arguments `a` and `b` are actually different before trying to provide a result. Otherwise you 'll get either a meaningless result or an outright exception. This is true of all the solutions presented here, including this one.

Comment: I think you should convert the result to int.

Comment: IMO, anything that is breaking out `Math.Log` and `double` to solve a bit-fiddling problem is doing it the hard way...

Comment: @MarcGravell: I 'd call it the short way, but that's not really the point. More importantly, why write extra code if there's no need to optimize?

Comment: we don't have the context; we can't assume that. Or at least, not from the question. The OP *has* now indicated that they don't need this, but...

Comment: @MarcGravell: True. This would definitely not be a good enough answer if we were talking about a library method.

Answer (score 2):

If they differ by one bit, xor should give you **just** that bit. So then you could shift to find which?

Perhaps needs some optimisation:

```
static int ChangedBit(int x, int y)
{
    uint bits = (uint)(x ^ y); // need uint to avoid backfill with shift
    int count = -1;
    while (bits != 0)
    {
        count++;
        bits >>= 1;
    }
    return count;        
}
```

Comment: What a pity that .net is lacking the Bitscan functions. That bites me quite often when doing some bitfiddling.

Comment: Marc, I agree that not using Log and double is good, but this optimization is for my application not required. Thanks

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what does `need uint to avoid backfill with shift` mean? (where is the backfill?)

Comment: @makerofthings7 the "backfill" is whatever becomes the values on the left-hand-side when you right-shift. When using `uint`, it back-fills with `0`. When using `int`, it back-fills with `0` for +ve values, and `1` for -ve values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily:

```
Math.Log(Math.Abs(a-b), 2)
```

Update:  fixed...

Comment: @Marc - the question states bytes. These are unsigned by default.

Comment: You need a "Log to base 2" function against (Maths.Abs(a-b))

Comment: Shouldn't that be more like `Log(Math.Abs(a-b), 2)`?

Comment: @Marc: although XOR is better solution

Comment: I fixed it, I guess, I was thinking TOO easy... ;-)

Comment: @David hmmm, yes, I missed that (byte). I always do my bit-fiddling on int or long, so I overlooked it ;p

Comment: IMO, anything that is breaking out `Math.Log` and `double` to solve a bit-fiddling problem is doing it the hard way...

Answer (score 1):

If you can count from zero, then `Math.Log(a^b,2)` does the job

Comment: @CodeInChaos - because my math only goes to *,/,+,- ;)

Comment: IMO, anything that is breaking out `Math.Log` and `double` to solve a bit-fiddling problem is doing it the hard way...

Answer (score 1):

```
var dif = a ^ b;
int bitNumber = 0;
while (dif != 0 && ((dif & 1) == 0)
{
   dif = dif >> 1;
   ++bitNumber;
}
// bitNumber now contains the zero relative bit that is different.
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist to write a LINQish version:

```
var firstBits = new BitArray(new byte[] { 3 });
var secondBits = new BitArray(new byte[] { 17 });

var lhs = firstBits.Cast<bool>().Select((b, i) => new { Bit = b, Index = i });
var rhs = secondBits.Cast<bool>().Select((b, i) => new { Bit = b, Index = i });

var differs = lhs.Zip(rhs, (l, r) => new { Left = l, Right = r })
                 .Where(zipped => zipped.Left.Bit != zipped.Right.Bit)
                 .Select(zipped => new { Index = zipped.Left.Index, LeftBit = zipped.Left.Bit, RightBit = zipped.Right.Bit });

foreach (var diff in differs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Differs in bit {0}:", diff.Index));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("   First is set to  {0}", diff.LeftBit));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("   Second is set to {0}", diff.RightBit));
}
```

#### Update

Due to the fact that the Zip operator is not a default in LINQ, you can get the implementation from Eric [out of his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx).

Comment: Is Zip a standard Linq operator?

Answer (score 0):

Others have observed that where two bytes differ in only one bit, an XOR operation will return a byte in which just that bit is set. But no one has yet suggested what to me is the obvious next step for establishing which bit that is:

```
public static int WhichBitDiffers(byte a, byte b)
{
    var xor = a ^ b;

    switch(xor)
    {
        case 0x80:
            return 7;
        case 0x40:
            return 6;
        case 0x20:
            return 5;
        case 0x10:
            return 4;
        case 0x8:
            return 3;
        case 0x4:
            return 2;
        case 0x2:
            return 1;
        case 0x1:
            return 0;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Values do not differ in exactly one bit");
    }
}
```

I bet the compiler / JITter will make this a nice compact jump lookup table, or something along those lines.